# Is it possible to drop a payload via anchored parachute?

Tags: aerodynamics, parachute, payload

Apologies if this is not the proper forum for this question -

Here's my situation:

[image]

I'm trying to drop a payload via parachute with some accuracy.  I'm worried that in the above setup, the line will interfere with parachute deployment or - if not deployment - operation during flight (imagine wind pushing the chute into the line).

I haven't tested this yet but plan to.  Does anyone know how the payload <> anchor connection might be engineered to ensure full deployment throughout the descent?

Comment: Instead of a parachute, could you have a slowed descent by gripping the line a little tighter?

Comment: @SnakeDoc - we've considered a slow-release pulley but unfortunately our "brand" depends on the parachute as a means of deployment.

Comment: In that case, I believe it was Mythbusters (no idea what episode(s)) who used a 4 line (in a square) from the air-to-ground and the object was attached to all 4 lines. So when it fell, the 4 lines kept is centered. Maybe a similar idea would work for you (more anchor lines).

Comment: @SnakeDoc I hadn't thought of that.  But yet another constraint is a single line.  Really our only variable here is the connection between the anchor line and the payload... I know that doesn't give us much to play with.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I have no other ideas. I think, depending on your environment conditions, you do run the risk of the parachute getting snared and preventing a good deployment. If your question doesn't get more attention here, I'd try over on the Engineering exchange - http://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @SnakeDoc.  I've actually posted there and got the suggestion to run the anchor line directly through the center of the parachute... I might try that.

Comment: I'm afraid this has nothing to do with aviation, so off-topic.

Comment: `unfortunately our "brand" depends on the parachute as a means of deployment` – nothing like letting your brand dictate engineering solutions! This seem backwards to anybody else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I'm trying to drop a payload via parachute with some accuracy.*

Cut a hole in the middle of the parachute, make its edge smooth and install a pipe through the center of the box that contains the payload. Run the line through the pipe and parachute and let the payload fall from the balloon. I believe the trick will work for small parachutes able to deliver up to 10 kg to the ground.

Answer (score 3):

If the hot air balloon is well anchored you can probably just use your original plan.  The winds aloft will push the balloon in the direction the wind is going, so the anchor rope should be at an angle relative to the ground.  When you drop the parachute, those same winds should keep the parachute/payload pushed clear of the anchor rope.  So long as the drag rope connecting the payload to the anchor rope is sufficiently long and the mechanism connecting the drag rope to the anchor rope is sufficiently slippery, you shouldn't have a problem.

I worry about Energizer777's solution though.  Mainly because the rope might be angled because of the winds aloft, as stated before.  Payloads on a parachute like to hang right below the parachute (more or less), and if the angle on the rope is sufficient the payload will simply end up resting on the rope itself, which might foul up and collapse the parachute since it's load will not be pulling on it properly.

All of that being said, that solution *will* work if you do this on a day with very calm, or non-existent wind...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't fix the angle with a single beam. Instead, use the following setup (90 degrees rotated for ASCII art):

```
            ,<)           __
/___________A____________/  \
\                        \__/
```

That is to say, use two beams to guide two rings along the anchor rope, and connect the parachute to the top of the A. Furthermore, connect the payload to the middle of the A (below the connecting bar) to balance the air friction of the parachute and the rope friction on the other side. This reduces the tilting torque.